# sms outbox not populating android

Tags: android, android-listview, sms, android-contentprovider, smsmanager

i am developing a sms messaging application as my first android project and i need to display sms conversation in a listview, i can fetch the inbox and sent items fine but when the user sends a new message (outgoing) the SmsManager only populates the sent table after it has been sent (which takes around 2500 milliseconds) but i want to display the message on the listview as soon as the user presses the send button (just like any other messaging application that displays the message as being sent in the conversation thread). sms manager does not populate the outbox either when it is in the process of sending the message. here is the code i am using to send the message.

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(address, null, ComposeMessageEditText.getText().toString(), sentPI, deliverPI);
```

i have been scratching my head over this for a while now and have read all the related questions on stackoverflow that i could find :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579324/displaying-a-message-being-sent-in-listview

Comment: @fejd surprisingly, it is more or less of a duplicate, but that question does not have any answers either. :(